# React - Caching data inside reducers?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, caching

## SUMMARY

Is it good to update caches inside reducers? I mean, can a cache be updated in every part of my front-end (components, screens, hooks, helpers...) or should this behavior be delegated to a specific part of the system?

## INTRODUCTION

In my app, every user have a field "totalFollowers".

I am storing the data of every user in the state of a React Context. To perform complex and pure updates based on previous state, I am using a reducer.

Also, I have implemented an in-memory LRU cache, just to avoid unnecessary DB requests and improve the user experience/performance. In this cache, I am storing some data which is also included in the React Context I have talked about... so, in both sides, the data has to be equal.

As I am updating the totalFollowers field of a specific user when the current user follows him, in my reducer I have the following:

```
export default (otherUsers, action) => {   
    switch (action.type) {
       case "follow-user": {
          const { userId, isFollowing } = action;

          const prevUserData = otherUsers.get(userId);

          return new Map([
             ...otherUsers,
            [
                userId,
                {
                   ...prevUserData,
                   totalFollowers: prevUserData.totalFollowers + (isFollowing ? 1 : -1)
                 ]
            ]
         );
       }

       ...
    }
}
```

## PROBLEM

As I said before... my cache have some data which is also included in the context (which uses the reducer I described), and "totalFollowers" is one of that data.

If my reducer gives me the possibility to access the state in a native/atomic way, I think that updating my cache inside it is a good idea. But, I have read that the only purpose of a reducer is to update state... I am afraid of that, as my idea of updating the cache inside the reducer could be an anti-pattern (avoid side effects inside pure functions)

What do you think? Is it "correct" to perform cache updates inside reducers?

```
import { usersCache } from "../../services/firebase/api/users"

export default (otherUsers, action) => {   
    switch (action.type) {
       case "follow-user": {
          const { userId, isFollowing } = action;

          const prevUserData = otherUsers.get(userId);

          const newTotalFollowers = prevUserData.totalFollowers + (isFollowing ? 1 : -1);

          usersCache.updateUser(userId, { totalFollowers: newTotalFollowers }); // merge update

          return new Map([
             ...otherUsers,
            [
                userId,
                {
                   ...prevUserData,
                   totalFollowers: newTotalFollowers
                 ]
            ]
         );
       }

       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you're overthinking. React state is basically already an in-memory cache. I don't think caching data in memory that is already in memory nets you any benefit. Where you'll see benefits of caching/memoization will be in your DB/network requests going ***into*** your state, and memoization of derived state coming ***out*** of your state to the UI. I would suggest looking into [Redux](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) for state management, and [Reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) for memoizing the state you are selecting. Redux-toolkit re-exports Reselect for convenience, BTW.

Comment: @DrewReese The think is that the state is destroyed when components unmount or the user session is closed (auth protected routes in my navigation). I am using that cache to avoid making DB requests, not to render stuff in the GUI, just to return cached data. Does redux solve this problem?

Comment: My point was that IMO you are trying to optimize the wrong part of your code. Yes, Redux is a global state management tool, uses reducers so it will be familiar if you are already using `useReducer` hooks, is built using the React context API, and scales very well. Redux-toolkit is an abstraction over redux and react-redux that include caching of queries (https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/overview) made to backend systems.

Comment: @DrewReese thx very much for your help, I will try to move to Redux ASAP. But, why do you think that caching user data is not needed? In my use case I am just saving the most fresh data (which can come from a pull-to-refresh in the user profile and can be modified (totalFollowers field) when pressing the typical follow button). I previously thought that my context could be the "cache", but it is impossible to consume a React context inside my api modules... and as it will be unmounted when the user signs out, I supposed that the memoization pattern could be good.

Comment: In the context to synchronize routes. In the cache to have the memoized results also then the context is unmounted (the user signs out).

Answer (score 1):

Cache and reducer are two different things.

##### Reducer

only when you want to build a mini state machine, you would choose to use reducer. But even doing that has its own problem, normally every update to any property of the state should trigger an update. Therefore reducer or not is mostly determined on the decision if the logic you are building are really condensed (or twisted) within a group of related properties.

##### Cache

I have a guts feeling you know cache more than I do. so I'll skip this part. You use cache to make sure things can be returned quickly if the same condition met, also you want to make sure you have at least more than two conditions. Otherwise it'll be a waste.

##### Context

You also mentioned context, but context is also different. It makes sure you can share a value. But the tricky part is that whenever a context value changes due to state change, it'll render all children underneath it.

##### Two cents

Normally you would think cache is very good supplement to reducer (or context). However the gain here is the cache, for instance, it saves time to skip calculation.

But don't bet on the render. Even when you fetch from the memory, the value wired to the reducer or context is still changed! Which means you might still get 100% re-render with the cache.

What I'm trying to say is, cache is a concept that has nothing to do with React. If you apply it, you only get its own benefit, but don't expect other benefits.

Comment: He can get the best of both parts! Using the cache to reduce networking costs and avoid RTTs is good. But, as you said, updating state will always cause a re-render. What about if he has two ways to update its Context state? As it is a UsersContext, he can perfectly provide an updateUser method, that will simply update the state (typically used in a pull-to-refresh, where re-render is necessary), and an addUser method, which, inside the reducer, before updating state will check if the record exists in the map (if yes, return same state, else return updated state)

Comment: Also, before updating the state, with the updateUser method, he could make a deep compare, and if previous record is equal, then return the current state, not the updated one.

Comment: BTW, I am not really into reducers… maybe conditionally updating the state or running a lodash deep comparison inside a reducer is an anti-pattern.

Comment: @Victor, you are right. You can take advantage on both, but my point is that the advantage is unique from each, there's no combined benefits as we normally would think. To be honest, in some way, they contradict a bit to each other.